# Seed torrent contents again after deleting .torrent file

Tags: bittorrent

Long time ago I downloaded a torrent with several Gbs of information.

This information is still in my system untouched (i.e.: haven't modified the contents of the torrent), but I've long lost the original .torrent file.

I know where this torrent is located online. Is there a way to start seeding again the contents of this torrent without having to download its entire contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every torrent software I know of will automatically use the content you have on your disk if you have it already downloaded.

Just re-download the torrent file and point it at the folder where you have the already downloaded files, the program should re-hash the files to make sure they are correct and it should show up as already downloaded once the torrent starts.